# What could be a high school experiment that involves changing a condition to get the highest yield of a certain product?

Tags: equilibrium

I am looking for ideas for a chemistry experiment and I am interested in doing one that has to do with the optimization of percentage yields. What could be a high school experiment that involves changing a certain condition to get the highest yield of a certain product?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the so-called Job's experiment. You prepare in advance 100 mL of two solutions of reactants which are supposed to have the same molar concentration. For example : CaCl2 0.1 M and Na2CO3 0.1 M. You take 9 test tubes in the same rack. Write 1 on the first, 2 on the second tube, etc. up to 9 on the last tube.

Now, with a plastic pipette, you put 1 mL of the CaCl2 solution in test tube 1, 2 mL CaCl2 in test tube 2, 3 mL of CaCl2 in test tube 3, etc. up to 10 mL in the tube 10. Then, you take another plastic pipette, and transfer 9 mL of NaCO3 solution in the tube 1, 8 mL of Na2CO3 in test tube 2, etc. up to 1 mL in tube 9. You mix thoroughly all tubes. You must see a white precipitate that settles in the bottom of  all tubes after a while. If you measure the height of the deposit, you will find that the highest amount is in the tube 5, if the stoichiometry is 1 + 1. If the mot important deposit is in another tube, it means that the stoichiometry is 1:2, oe 2:3, or any other ratio.

You may change and use any other combination of compounds. You will find that in the mixture CuSO4 plus NaOH, the stoichiometry is not 1:2, as you might suspect, as the precipitate is not Cu(OH)2, but 3Cu(OH)2·CuSO4.

Comment: 9 or 10 tubes ?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] A rapid photolysis experiment centered around B-12 ( a photocatalyst, see, for example, [this article](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2018/ra/c7ra13037f#!divAbstract) [and also here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29271445)) plus some dissolved B-Complex, where the removal of the solution coloration with ordinary sunlight can be witnessed in hours, may be of interest.

One can have several clear plastic contains that have varying amounts of tape limiting light exposure to demonstrate the impact of sunlight. I would take pictures to document the comparative relative transformation over time in solution coloration.

An alternate longer term experiment, based on the article ['Photosynthesis: Response to high temperature stress'](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Anjana_Jajoo/publication/262111495_Photosynthesis_Limitations_in_Response_to_High_Temperature_Stress/links/55ae202f08aed614b09830f9.pdf) in Journal of Photochemistry and Photobiology B: Biology, to quote from the paper:

> Temperature is continually increasing due to global warming and has become a serious threat to crop yield. Temperatures above the normal optimum are termed as heat stress (HS) which disturbs the normal cellular homeostasis leading to retardation in growth and development and even death in extreme conditions...Although the plant growth is controlled by a multitude of physiological, biochemical, and molecular processes, photosynthesis is a key phenomenon, which contributes substantially to the crop yield...Photosynthesis is highly sensitive to high temperature stress and is often inhibited before other cell functions are impaired [4].

So, the high school experiment would be to display over time, the effect of light/heat on a living plant with implications to global food production.